# How to make a simple borderless button in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, button, border, borderless

Quite simply, I'm trying to create a borderless button in a MATLAB GUI. The reasons are mostly aesthetics, so no need for a debate on why it should be borderless.

I already know that this cannot be done using the built-in MATLAB uicontrol alone, since the border of the button is not an accessible property in MATLAB. Thus, the underlying JAVA code (upon which MATLAB is written), must be accessed in order to manipulate the border. This is where I get lost, since I've only ever programmed in MATLAB.

I followed an example from here:
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/borderless-button-used-for-plot-properties

But I'm still not getting a borderless button.

Here is a simple code example (NOTE the use of Yair Altman's findjobj which is available on the MATLAB file exchange):

```
f=figure('Menubar','none', 'Position',[200 200 300 200]);
p=uipanel(f, 'BackgroundColor', [0 0 1]);
h = uicontrol('parent', p, ...
'Style','pushbutton', ...
'String','click', ...
'TooltipString', 'you should click this' ...
'Units','normalized', ...
'Position',[0.3 0.3 0.5 0.5], ...
'BackgroundColor', [0 0 1]);
jh = findjobj(h);
jh.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()); 
%attempt 1 does not remove border
jh.border=[];                                                
%attempt 2 does not remove border
jh.setBorder([]);                                            
%attempt 3 does not remove border
jh.border=javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();     
%attempt 4 does not remove border
```

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, but ***MATLAB GUI*** and ***aesthetics*** shouldn't be used in the same paragraph ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud add two lines:

```
jh.setBorderPainted(false);    
jh.setContentAreaFilled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you mean with "borderless".

Looking at the example on the Web page you posted, I assume you are looking for something like an "invisible" pushbutton.

If so, you might consider this alternative way:

- insted of having a pushbutton you might have a `static text uicontrol`
- make its `backgroundcolor` the same of the GUI backgroundcolor (it will become "invisible" and without any border)
- do not set any `string` in the `static text uicontrol`
- set the `enable` property of the `static text uicontrol` to `off`
- define, for the `static text uicontrol` the `ButtonDownFcn`
- write the code you want to execute by pushing the pushbutton in the `ButtonDownFcn`

When you press the mouse button on the "invisible" `static text uicontrol`, its `ButtonDownFcn` will be executed.

You just have to remember ... were the "invisible" `static text uicontrol` is.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. By border-less I mean it just looks like text floating on a background without any rectangle enclosing the text. I did indeed consider using the static text uicontrol to create this borderless appearance. The problem with the static text uicontrol is that it creates a new problem for me. Static text is automatically aligned to the top (not the center) of its rectangle space. This would also still require editing on the Java handle object, since again, vertical text alignment is not an accessible uicontrol property in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

The border is affected by the  fly-over appearance feature. http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-button-highlighting
You need to add

```
jh.setFlyOverAppearance(true);
```

Worked for me.